# Absolutely positioning an image and scroll bar

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to absolute a 'hero' image at the top of the page which is wider than the main page content. The main page content is 960px. The image is 1200px. I only want horizontal scrollbars to appear if the browser window is less than 960px wide. I have considered using media queries to set the html element to overflow hidden if less than 1200px, and then add them back at 960px. However, that doesn't cleanly solve the problem.

Sample Page:
http://riverdistrictstudio.com/overflow/

Comment: what about using it as background image? `background: url(yourimage.jpg) center top fixed no-repeat`

Comment: That is not really ideal, this image is considered to be 'content' and may be part of a slide show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a background image, you could try wrapping it in another `<div>` which has `overflow:hidden` and `width:100%`. You can see it working with a dummy image in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXqRA/).

Comment: You can see it working with _your_ image and markup [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Q4Bv/1/)